# Reuse WC_Admin_List_Table_Products from woocommerce to customize table and actions

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to include `WC_Admin_List_Table_Products` class in my custom plugin so I can re-use woocommerce product admin table in my plugin and customize the actions and buttons on different page. How I can do that? I have tried different ways as.

```
    include_once( WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/woocommerce/include/admin/list-tables/class-wc-admin-list-table-products.php' );
    $wc_list_table = new WC_Admin_List_Table_Products();
```

Even using the plugin_dir_path.

```
    include_once plugin_dir_path('woocommerce/include/admin/list-tables/class-wc-admin-list-table-products.php');
    $wc_list_table = new WC_Admin_List_Table_Products();
```

Both are not working at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use it like this:

```
require_once( WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/woocommerce/includes/admin/list-tables/class-wc-admin-list-table-products.php' );

class Extended_WC_Admin_List_Table_Products extends Extended_WP_List_Table {

}
```

and then call your new class in the right location:

```
$wc_list_table = new Extended_WC_Admin_List_Table_Products();
```

Comment: How do I print out the table then?

Answer (score 0):

Using plugin_dir_path will not work as plugin_dir_path will return current plugin file or directory path. Replace below line with your line

```
include_once( WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/woocommerce/includes/admin/list-tables/class-wc-admin-list-table-products.php' );
```

You have made small mistake in writting directory name of '**include**'. Correct directory name is '**includes**'.